# CloudKit how to modify existing record (swift 3)

Tags: swift, cloudkit

How can I modify an existing CloudKit record?

I receive a record from CloudKit with this code:

```
let name = tmpVar as! String

let container = CKContainer.default()
let privateDatabase = container.privateCloudDatabase
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "email == %@", name)
var query = CKQuery(recordType: "MainTable", predicate: predicate)
privateDatabase.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (results, error) -> Void in
if error != nil {
    pass
}
else {
    if (results?.count)! > 0 {
        for result in results! {
            self.likedArr.append(result)
        }

        if let checker = self.likedArr[0].object(forKey: "like") as? String {
            print ("CHEKER IS \(checker)")
            let intChecker = Int(checker)
            let result = intChecker! + 1
        } else {
            print ("EMPTY")
        }
    } else {
        print ("Login is incorrect")
    }

    OperationQueue.main.addOperation({ () -> Void in
        //   self.tableView.reloadData()
        //   self.tableView.isHidden = false
        //   MBProgressHUD.hide(for: self.view, animated: true)})}
```

and how to return it back modified value of "like" key to the owner "name"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the query, you get an array of [`CKRecord`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckrecord) objects. Use the subscript to edit the record:

```
record["key"] = value as CKRecordValue
```

when you're finished, take the CKRecord and use either [`CKModifyRecordsOperation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckmodifyrecordsoperation) or [`CKDatabase.save(_:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckdatabase/1449114-save) to save it back to the server.

Answer (score 1):

When you get the records from the cloud, you can cast them to CKRecords.
In this CKRecord object you just modify the values you want to update, and then save it all again to the cloud. The CKRecordId must be the same, otherwise you'll just make a new record.

here is how to modify the records:

```
 MyCKRecord.setValue(object, forKey: "myKey")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing my solution:

```
self.likedArr[0].setValue(1, forKey: "like")
    let saveOper = CKModifyRecordsOperation()
    saveOper.recordsToSave = self.likedArr
    saveOper.savePolicy = .ifServerRecordUnchanged

    saveOper.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error in

    if saveOper.isFinished == true {

    }
    }
    privateDatabase.add(saveOper)
```

Comment: the `saveOper.isFinished` block was never called though. I just checked for any errors. and if none, continued my processes.